# Best practice for laptop: sleep or shutting down

Tags: laptop, sleep, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer care: Hibernate, Sleep or Shut Down?](https://superuser.com/questions/208506/computer-care-hibernate-sleep-or-shut-down)

My laptop takes forever to load up.  I normally don't ever shut down.  I just close the lid and put it in my bag.  Is this a bad practice or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: I do this all the time. Laptop's set to hibernate on closing the lid.

Comment: Are you running your laptop usually on batteries, or is it usually connected to the electricity?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do the same thing, this would only be a problem as far as I can tell if you leave it in there long enough that the battery dies (it takes power to keep data in ram).  If you ran it down it would be the same as just turning it off incorrectly anyway, which isn't a huge issue of you use a journaling filesystem like ext4.

Comment: depending on how long you intend to keep the laptop putting it merely into sleep mode may adversely affect the life of the battery.

Comment: I also tend to do the same thing.  If you are running older versions of Windows you may need to reboot occasionally, but I have a dual-boot system with Windows 7 and Debian GNU/Linux that is only rebooted for Windows Updates or Linux kernel upgrades.  No problems so far.

Answer (score -2):

Consider using the *Hybrid Sleep* option instead; it doesn't use battery power and it may resume more quickly:

> Hybrid sleep is another new power-saving feature designed primarily for desktop computers. Hybrid sleep saves any open documents and programs to memory and to your hard disk, and then puts your computer into a low-power state.
>
> Unlike mobile PCs, desktop computers typically don't have battery-based power backup. So if a sudden power failure occurs to a desktop computer in standard sleep mode, data loss could occur.
>
> But with hybrid sleep turned on, Windows can restore your work from your hard disk. On desktop computers, hybrid sleep is typically turned on by default.
>
> When hybrid sleep is turned on, clicking Sleep automatically puts your computer into hybrid sleep. When hybrid sleep is turned off, or if your computer doesn't support hybrid sleep, clicking Sleep puts the computer to sleep.
>
> To turn hybrid sleep on or off:
>
> Open Power Options by clicking the **Start** button , clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **System and Maintenance**, and then clicking **Power Options**.
>
> On the **Select a power plan** page, click **Change plan settings** under the selected plan.
>
> On the Change settings for the plan page, click **Change advanced power settings**.
>
> On the Advanced settings tab, expand Sleep, expand **Allow hybrid sleep**, and then do one of the following:
>
> If you are using a mobile PC, click On battery or Plugged in (or both), click the arrow, and then click On.
>
> If you are using a desktop computer, click Setting, click the arrow, and then click On.
>
> Click **OK**, and then click **Save** changes.

- Quoted from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-off-a-computer-frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: -1 for saying that hybrid sleed doesn't use any battery power.  It uses exactly the same amount of power as ordinary sleep, it just doesn't matter if power is interupted because the entire system state is ALSO saved to disc.

Comment: Also, Hybrid sleep is generally not recommended for laptops, as having batteries they are not sensitive to power outages, and they usually have their own solutions for batterly low conditions (in this situation they most often wake up from sleep shortly and hibernate).

Comment: Oh. I'm taking a Windows Client course (TestOut LabSim, pretty reputable) and it says otherwise about the battery issue and also recommends hybrid for laptops! So: apologies, I was trained wrong.

Comment: Hybrid sleep can also cause some device drivers to choke and die even worse than normal sleep. Caveat emptor!

Comment: I don't see that `Hybrid Sleep` is an option for "When I close the lid:". Am I missing something? It gives four options, "Do nothing", "Sleep", "Hibernate", and "Shut Down".